# css style are not getting applied in github when deployed

Tags: html, css, github, deployment

I am trying to deploy a small html and css project on github but css styles are not getting applied after deployment. I am very new to github and I don't know what is the probelem. Any help will be appreciated.

HERE IS THE MY REPO OF MY PROJECT:https://github.com/Subhodeep014/Frontend_Mentor_testimonial

Answer (score 0):

In your header, you used a double single quote instead of one.

###### the wrong code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testimonials</title>
    <link rel=''stylesheet''  href="style.css">
</head>
```

###### the correct one:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testimonials</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="style.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but still I am having the same problem

Comment: the page loads now, have you fixed it?

Comment: Yes @lekan1554. and thank you for your help. I think i was being little impatient on that day but when i checked after few minutes, it was working fine.

Comment: Alright, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I Check the link and pages load Properly with css[View Link](https://subhodeep014.github.io/Frontend_Mentor_testimonial/)

Comment: thank you Sam for your help. I was little impatient at that time but  when i checked later the website was working fine.